# javascript - 2 promises sent and results of the second one come first - how to handle it?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an input field that when user types in, I need to do an HTTP call to get some results related to the search query. 
Now, user types some word and I call this HTTP service to get response. now user types again and I call the service again. 
The question is not related to debounce (you can assume I have already implement it ot not, doesn't matter)

sometimes the results of the first query come after the second one (for example if the results of the first one are big). How can I solve the issue?
I don't know a way to cancel the first http call (when we send the second)

Comment: You can cancel `fetch()` request

Comment: Take a look at this: https://medium.com/@slavik57/async-race-conditions-in-javascript-526f6ed80665